Existence of graphs such that the symmetric difference of neighbourhoods has size n/4.
Does anyone know of a way to construct a graph $G = (V,E)$ on $n$ vertices with the following property. For every two distinct vertices $u$ and $v$ the size of $N(u) \setminus N(v) = n/4$, where $N(u)$ denotes the neighbourhood of $u$ in $G$. Apologies if this is a stupid question I'm not so familiar with graph theory literature.
Some thoughts: 
• If one takes the Erdős–Rényi random graph with edge probability 1/2, the expected size of $N(u) \setminus N(v) = n/4$. So it seems somewhat reasonable to me that such graphs should exist. 
• If one takes a strongly regular graph with certain parameters one can guarantee the property, but I've no idea if graphs satisfying the parameters exist. For example, if we take a n/2-regular graph where every pair of vertices (adjacent or non-adjacent) has n/4 common neighbours, then such a graph would fulfil my criteria. But in fact, these parameters are impossible by basic properties of strongly regular graphs. 
• It would also be okay if $|N(u) \setminus N(v) - n/4| \le \delta$ for some constant (or maybe even some very small function of $n$).

The exact problem is a specific case of strongly-regular graphs, but the degree you tried isn't correct.
Since $|N(u)\setminus N(v)|=|N(v)\setminus N(u)|$, we also have $|N(u)|=|N(v)|$ and the graph is $d$-regular for some $d$.
Now let's count the triples $(u,v,w)$ such that $w\in N(u)\setminus N(v)$ (here we could have $v=w$). Our initial requirement gives $n(n-1)n/4$ such triples, but since there are $d(n-d)$ pairs containing any given $w$, we must have $n(n-1)/4=d(n-d)$. This gives $n/4=|d-n/2|^2$, so it follows that $n$ is square and $d=n/2\pm\sqrt {n/2}$.
Therefore we have a strongly-regular graph with parameters $(n,n/2\pm\sqrt{n/2},n/4\pm\sqrt{n/2},n/4\pm\sqrt{n/2})$. There are at least some cases where these exist: there are two $(16,6,2,2)$ strongly-regular graphs.
The fact that the last two parameters are equal means that there is a corresponding symmetric incomplete block design, so you might need to research how much is known about these objects.

Really helpful answer; do you happen to know any references on the connection between strongly regular graphs and these block designs I'm not familiar.
